# 1080x1920 for a CNN is too big, how to optimize it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to analyze screenshot from Among Us to make a bot.

Input: screenshot 1080x1920

Ouptut: left, right, up, down, x_click, y_click, LeftMouseIsPressed

```
def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(64, 64), strides=(1, 1),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(1080,1920,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,1888569,4096]
```

Question: Is there something that I can do to reduce my input size ? How people deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to decrease the resolution of your image to fit the amount of memory you have. Let's say you decrease the image size by 8.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.jpg") # 1080x1920 image 520K
foo = im.resize((135,240),Image.ANTIALIAS)
foo.save("test_135_240.jpg") #135x240 image 7.8K
```

If you have 1M images then this will be approx 8Gb. So you need to check if this will fit on your graphics card. Don't forget that you'll need space for transformations as well.

[Other useful info here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/how-do-i-handle-large-images-when-training-a-cnn)

Comment: Why not `tf.image.resize(image, (height, width))`? Then you don't add another dependency

Comment: Fair play, I didn't know tensorflow included this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tf.keras.layers...Resizing`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Resizing) as your first layer, it will reduce the image size:

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(
    height, width
)
```

Reduce it until it fits in memory.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thank you !
And have a good New Year :)